# Resolving "prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol" error

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, syntax-error, protocols

Why is this code in Xcode giving me the error that "prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol"? If you could explain what a prefix attribute is and how it interacts with the interface/protocol, that would be great. Here is the code:

```
@interface HellowWorldViewController() UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label; //error on both calls of property
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
@interface HellowWorldViewController() UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Is invalid because you look to be trying to specify a superclass and protocol adherence on a continuation category. You can't specify a superclass on a continuation category. You should probably have

```
@interface HellowWorldViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Or, if you already have the interface, then

```
@interface HellowWorldViewController() <UITextFieldDelegate>
```